# Check if function exists from external file in Python

Tags: python-2.7, function, python-import

Currently I have a file ***file1.py*** with the following variable *name_functions=['a','b','c']*

I would like to check from ***file1.py*** whether an external file ***file2.py*** has the functions *a,b,c*. It's important to highlight that such functions are not defined for any particular class in ***file2.py***. The second file (***file2.py***) is only a python file that has the definition of a bunch of multiple functions that are intended to be run from ***file1.py***
Is there any way to check the existence of the functions I have in my list? If so, do they have to be run or is there a way to only verify if they are defined in ***file2.py***?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

New answer!!

Script 1: I'll add 2 random functions in this script

```
def addNumbers(a, b):
    print("Sum is ", a + b)
 
def subtractNumbers(a, b):
    print("Difference is ", a-b)
```

Script 2: I'll check if functions exist in Script 1 before executing it

```
from Script1 import *

if "addNumbers" in dir():
    print "true"
    addNumbers(1,2)
else:
    print "false"

if "sumNumbers" in dir():
    print "true"
    sumNumbers(1,2)
else:
    print "false"
```

Gives you the answer:

[image]

There are few other ways to do it, for example we could even use try accept to check if it's defined or not.

```
try:
    variable
except NameError:
    print("Not available!")
else:
    print("Yes it's available!")
```

Answer (score -1):

First File:

```
with open('file2.py', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    print (content)
content_file.close()
identifier = "name_functions=['a','b','c']"
if identifier in content: print ("true")
else: print ("false")
```

If Second File has wanted definition:

```
name_functions=['a','b','c']
```

Output from First File is:

```
name_functions=['a','b','c']
true
```

If Second File does not have correct definition:

```
name_functions=['a','b']
```

Output from First File is:

```
name_functions=['a','b']
false
```

Which ever actions you intend to do with or without the correct definition in second file, you may do so with the if statement.

Comment: I have a question with your answer. It seems to me that what you are doing is looking in list generated by read() a match between the string in the list name_functions. This might be misleading because it could be a variable called 'a' rather a function. Plus, could you explain to me in more details how to run a function from the first file if this one exists?

Comment: This is not a good way to check if the functions actually exist.

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow I overlooked this and thanks to your comment I'm back to redeem myself

Comment: @little_mice the captain is right, it's not a good way at all. sorry I'm a little late haha. you probably know the answer by now. but for the sake of leaving a good answer here, let's solve this. there are two questions, one is how to know if the function exist. another is whether you require running the function in order to know if it exists. Basically if you run a function you can already tell if it's there or not and it's not practical because it wastes time. I'll post a answer without running the function.